# Update-grub only work in sda1

Tags: partition, grub2, grub

**Introduction**

I have 3 linux distribution:

```
 1. Ubuntu (22.04) on /dev/sda1
 2. Ubuntu (22.04) on /dev/sda5
 3. Manjaro (22.04) on /dev/sda9
```

---

**Question**

When I try to run `update-grub` from except `/dev/sda1` it's always doesn't take effect to GRUB2 menu. Everytime I take change to my grub2 configuration I must reboot and `update-grub` from `/dev/sda1`, Are there some method or tricks for `update-grub` not always from `/dev/sda1`?

Btw I'm use UEFI/GPT

---

Comment: `/dev/sda` maybe?

Comment: You can add a 40_custom entry that boots the other install (not sure about manjaro) as Ubuntu has link to most current kernel in /boot. http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages or you can use  a configfile to boot into other install's grub.cfg. https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config More info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive/344359#344359